# Are request and response part of two different TCP connections?

Tags: http, networking, tcp

I am very new to networking, so this might sound simple. Though I have tried to look [here](http://www.loriotpro.com/Products/On-line_Documentation_V5/LoriotProDoc_EN/C3-Introduction_to_Network_Supervision/C3-F8_TCP_Overview_EN.htm) and [here](http://www.geekinterview.com/question_details/12893) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) and have got few basics of TCP, there are few questions whose answers I am not certain about.

1. Is a request and response part of 2 different TCP establishments. To explain that :

Is a connection established, kept alive until all packets are delivered, request sent and connection closed for each request and same happens for its response.

or

A connection is opened, request sent, connection kept alive, response arrives and connection closed.

2. Is the ACK number always 1 + sequence number of sent segment.

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is a request and response part of 2 different TCP establishments

You need just 3 packets to handshake and establish a bidirectional TCP connection. So no, you do not establish TCP connection for receiving and sending parts.

On the other hand, there is a sutdown() system call which allows to shutdown a part of the bidirectional connection. See man shutdown(2). So there is a possibility to establish a unidirectional connection by opening a bidirectional and then shutdown one of the sides.

> 2. Is the ACK number always 1 + sequence number of sent segment.

We usually do not send ACK for every received packet. There are also selective ACKs, retransmissions etc. So in general, the answer is no, the ACK number is not always seq + 1.

On the other hand, if you are sending a small amount of data and waiting for the confirmation, no errors or packet loss occurred, most probably there will be just one packet with that data and one ACK with seq + 1.

Hope that helps.